# How to set DialogResult AFTER button is pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a password window using Windows Form Designer, except the context is a little different. There are several input fields, and one of them is password protected. There is a "Change" button that spawns a new password window on top of the home window. The user enters a password attempt and presses "OK". I need a way to have the OK button check the password and then send a `DialogResult.OK` back to the home window, or display an "incorrect password" if the attempt is incorrect. This means I can't set the `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.OK` initially, so I'm not sure how to do this.

Currently I set the `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.OK` in the click event function, but obviously this sets it for the next click, not the current one, so the user has to press the OK button twice.

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string passwordAttempt = textBoxPassword.Text;
    if( passwordAttempt.CompareTo("pass") == 0 )
    {
        this.buttonOK.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

One possible solution is to trigger a second event through the code (not sure how to do this). Or alternatively, is there a better way to do password windows I'm not thinking of in this situation?

Comment: Assign this.DialogResult instead.  What you *should* do is set the OK button's DialogResult with the designer, so it becomes the default button with the heavy border and the Enter key works, and if you are not happy about the password set this.DialogResult back to None.

Comment: Yup, that works.

Comment: How would that work if the user enters a second attempt? The DialogResult would then start as None and have to be reset again

Comment: If you have a button set to DialogResult.OK and press that button, the form DialogResult property is set to be the same as the clicked button DialogResult property BEFORE entering your click event handler. If, inside the event handler, you change the form's DialogResult property to None then the form doesn't close and you are free to attempt again the procedure until you are satisfied with the user input

Comment: Add `this.Close();`

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I've done that but the OK button still is not the default button, so I can't hit enter and have it send the password attempt without using the mouse to click or tabbing to it

Comment: Have you considered using the `Closing`, `Validating` and/or `Validate` event handlers for the form?  Those might be better ways of checking your PW field and setting DialogResult.

Comment: Assign the Form.AcceptButton property to your button to get the enter behavior you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set the `AcceptButton` of the dialog to `buttonOK` (the OK button). You can do this either in code or designer.
2. Set the `DialogResult` of the dialog form, not the button.

Code:

```
this.AcceptButton = buttonOK;

...

private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string passwordAttempt = textBoxPassword.Text;
    if (passwordAttempt.CompareTo("pass") == 0)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }
}
```